# Simplify index nested entries

Tags: indexing

I want create index nested entries and typeset the indexed word with the same command.

For simple entries like `\index{foo}` I can solve this with some macro  or `\index*{foo}` or `\Index{foo}` with the packages `index` and `hvindex`respectively, but the problem is with nested entries like `foo!bar` where I want type only "`bar`" in the text and obtain a correct nested entry in the index, that is:

```
foo
  bar, 1
```

According to manual of `hvindex`, this package do just that, but I  am unable to obtain any nested entry with this package in an updated TeXLive 2013. This MWE type correctly "`bar`" in main text but only "`bar, 1`" as index entry in my computer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[makeidx]{hvindex}
\begin{document}
\Index{foo!bar}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Instead, `index` make the correct nested entry but write "`foo!bar`" as is in the body text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\index*{foo}
\index*{foo!bar}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since TeX Live 2013 has not yet been released, it's best to stick with the 2012 version, when reporting problems. However the problem seems present also in the 2012 release.

Comment: ehh...right, right, ... but you know, warm-blooded users cannot live too long on a frozen release.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in `hvindex`; a missing `#1` in one of the calls to `\index` made by the internal macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[makeidx]{hvindex}

%%% fix \IndexXXii
\def\IndexXXii#1!#2@#3@#4\IndexNIL{%
  \ifx\relax#3\relax            %               no @ in last arg
    \def\hvTemp{#2}%
    \ifx\hvTemp\hvEncap\index{#1!{#2}}#2\else
      \ifx\hvIDXfont\hvIDXfontDefault\index{#1!#2}#2% <--- Here a % and #1 were missing
      \else\index{#1!#2@\hvIDXfont{#2}}\hvIDXfont{#2}\fi\fi%
  \else\index{#1!\protect#2@#3}#3\fi}

\begin{document}
\Index{foo}

\Index{foo!bar}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fixing this bug in the line 62 of hvindex.sty seem to work perfectly. Grazie mile!

Comment: Similarly, line 70 have should be   `\ifx\hvIDXfont\hvIDXfontDefault\index{#1!#2!{#3}}#3%` for the next level of nesting.

Comment: @Fran This seems sensible. I didn't go that far. ;-)